# Close and flag links do nothing on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, mobile-web

This morning (it's about six AM here) I find that I can no longer submit close votes; the link just jumps to the beginning of the page.

I'm on iOS, using a third-party browser called Grazing, but a brief check with Mobile Safari shows the same problem there.

Here on Meta, where my score is much lower, I only get a "delete" link on my own question, and that works fine. (Oops `:-)`)

- Update: As per comments, this affects the "flag" link, too, which doesn't even scroll to the top of the page.
- Update 2: Latest comment suggests this affects Android, too.
- Update 3: This also affects desktop computers when viewing mobile (when you click "mobile" in the footer)
- Update 4: [Dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187196/unable-to-flag-or-close-from-mobile-site) mentions Windows 8, too; simply deleting platform-specific tags

Comment: Repro, SO, Mobile Safari, iOS 6.1.3, iPhone 4S.

Comment: Also reproducing here, flags & close broken on iOS 7 beta 2. It does work with the full site though.

Comment: Repro on mobile safari, iOS 5.1.1, iPod Touch 4th gen.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I guess "It does work with the full site" means that on IOS when you switch from the mobile view to the "full site" view from the link in the footer, these features work?  Confirming that, and thanks for the (obvious!) workaround!

Comment: @tripleee: Do other JavaScript features work? The inbox? The share link?

Comment: Inbox works, not sure where to find a share link. They are visible on the full site (which works fine anyway, as per workaround note) but I don't see them anywhere on the mobile site, which is what I'm having issues with. Are they hidden somewhere?

Comment: Having the exact se problem on android (Jellybean): can't close or flag while using the mobile version.

Comment: I get the same problem when I view the mobile site on my computer. (Scroll down and click "mobile" in the footer)

Comment: Repro, SO, Mobile Chrome, iOS 6.13, iPhone 5. Works when I switch to desktop view.

Comment: Yup, same here on Android 4.1.2, noticed it since yesterday.

Comment: As of yesterday, this was still a problem on Android (Nexus 4).

Comment: This isn't working on ELU either ( safari, iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.4)

Comment: Repro here on an iPhone 4S running the latest iOS. Notably, If I switch to the full site view, both links work fine.

Comment: I just went on meta to report the same bug. Looks like there won't be a duplicate!

Comment: I'm facing this problem on both iPhone 4 (6.1.3) and iPhone 5 (6.1.4) Safari. This problem is recent, never happened before. I once thought close isn't working because I reviewed 50 close votes, but it turned out it has nothing to do with review.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out in the next build (happening in a few minutes).

Comment: You know you *totally* want to roll out a fix for [the mobile delete link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184482/yes-im-really-sure-i-want-to-delete-that-post) in the next-next build too. *wink wink, nudge nudge* But thank you, this bug was driving me crazy.

Comment: Unaccepting because I still can't flag answers. Should I file a separate report for that?

Comment: @tripleee looks like I can flag answers as well in the mobile view, check again.

Comment: Nope, flag is still broken, both in Grazing and Safari, both on questions and answers (apparently excepting my own questions ...)

Comment: @tripleee Ah found it, the flag link was not a proper anchor in mobile, no `href="#"` so mobile safari didn't treat it as a link....so mobile had *two* problems.  Unfortunately, the second doesn't present as a problem when testing the mobile theme in Chrome.  A fix is going out in the next build, making the anchor valid HTML.

Comment: Yay, works now; thanks!

Comment: Confirmed. Before today, failure to popup flag or closevote dialog was reproducible on Opera Mini 5.0.18741, in mobile view only, not reproducible in full site view. Problem is no longer reproducible.

Comment: There might still be a bug with that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188673/cant-close-a-question-with-custom-reason-on-mobile-an-error-occurred

Answer (score 9):

Due to a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186246/close-popup-doesnt-appear-after-editing-the-question-without-refreshing-the-pag/186372#186372) to fix the dialogs not appearing after an inline edit on the full site, the event handlers are no longer bound correctly on the mobile site due to differences in the HTML.

Either the mobile site HTML needs to be modified to include `.container` and `#content` elements, or the handlers need to be bound differently.

A quick look suggests that instead of binding delegate handlers so high up in the DOM, they could instead just be bound on `.answer` and `.question` and then rebound in the case of a realtime update using a handler for the `refreshEdit` event. It's possible that there's something that would make this approach ineffective, however, and unfortunately I don't have time now to check.

Comment: How come you're not working for SE yet? ;)