# Can't close a question with custom reason on mobile – "an error occurred"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, vote-to-close, mobile-web

When closing a question on mobile, writing a custom close reason in the "off topic" dialog, I get

> An error occurred; please try again
>
> [image]

… and the question stays open. Closing with a predefined reason however works fine. This is just on mobile, tested under iOS 6 as well as the mobile view on desktop browsers.

What gives?

Comment: I just tried to close this with the custom reason: "This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible" but... it didn't work. Android 2.3.

Comment: Oops, flagged it instead. Sorry! +1 :P

Comment: can anyone still reproduce that?

Comment: @m0sa Seems to have been resolved, so you can close this.